# Java End to End functional testing inside container, minimum mocking

Tags: testing, smoke-testing

I am looking for gradle and jenkins friendly testing framework, that supports minimum mocking and works inside container like IBM Websphere Process Server.  A little bit about our product and my requirements :

We have a system that works inside bank and receives through MQ, payment data which can be xml or flat file (but this doesn't matter) as we have parser for all formats. After we parse it we populate our entity model with it and then start a business process (JBPM) that in turns calls EJB services for validating these entities, performs functional checks execute db read and write and finally drop message to MQ, if payment is validated.
  So, in shorts we receive something performs some functional logic and then we send something out and all this happens in single XA transaction.

Requirements:
We use jenkins and gradle to build our system what I would like to do is to have this system tested end to end (smoke testing) such a way that there is a receiver that receives a file (based upon business scenarios) received data can vary, and this testing system should be able to start the process and in between like check point I should be able to check the status of entities (created after parsing) and in the end check the output data if its correct. 
I don't want to mock anything as that would beat the purpose of testing real code. all the EJB's invoked (in process flows) are using DI to actually call java Pojo.

We have been using custom made testing solution but either they are very complex or lack flexibility. There is no UI testing involved here so I am not looking for that either. This testing should be easily integrated with jenkins such that nightly build also test the identified scenarios automatically.

Please ask for more info if needed. Thanks